# Joomla 1.5 Media Manager sets incorrect file permissions when uploading

Tags: windows, cms, joomla

Howdy all, I have a Joomla 1.5 installation running on Windows Server 2008, installed via the Web Platform Installer.

When uploading images with the media manager (native uploader, not the flash bulk uploader), the files arrive on the server correctly, but are given incorrect permissions.  Specifically, the IIS_IUSRS group is not given access to the file.  I might be incorrect about what group/user is SUPPOSED to get access to the files, but so far, I've found that unless I give IIS_IUSRS access to the uploaded files, they won't appear on the site or in the media manager (appear as broken images).  Once I give IIS_IUSRS permission to the files, they work fine.

So far, all the research I've done has led me to linux specific fixes that involve either changing the umask on the server, or directly modifying the Joomla codebase to add an appropriate chmod command to the upload process, but I really don't want to modify Joomla directly.  I have to believe there's a setting here somewhere that will do the job, either on the Joomla or Windows side of the equation.

Any thoughts?

Scott

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion describing the same problem: [How come when I add IIS_IUSRS RW access to a folder, it doesn't automatically allow ISUR RW access?](https://serverfault.com/questions/179627/how-come-when-i-add-iis-iusrs-rw-access-to-a-folder-it-doesnt-automatically-all)

I fixed the issue by changing the Anonymous Authentication credentials to 'Application Pool Identity', which is the NETWORK SERVICE identity and should have read access to the images directory.

All is described in the article above.

So, go to IIS manager, go to Authentication, right click on 'Anonymous Authentication' => edit, and change the setting there.